# regular expression for tokenizing a white-space-delimitated string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to tokenize a result string from cscope symbol search, which is composed of a few fields delimited by white space:

```
/path/including whitespace/to/file.ext function_name line_number <any_content>
```

using regular expression.

I'm using python, and the regex I've tried is:

```
r'^(?P<File>[\w\W\s]+?)[\s]{1}(?P<Function>[\w]+[\s]{1}(?P<Linenum>[0-9]+)[\s]{1})(?P<Content>[\w\W\s]+)'
```

It doesn't work and I find it so hard to figure out a solution since there are so many white-spaces in that string. Note that both the path group (File) and the content group (Content) can have white spaces in them. I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

**UPDATE**

- The right output would be a list of strings like this:

  ['/path/including whitespace/to/file.ext', 'function_name', 'line_number', '']
- All filenames are with an extension, e.g., .cpp.
- I cannot modify the
  paths to remove spaces (not my own decision to make).

Comment: What is the 'right' output?

Comment: There needs to be more information.  Do all the filenames end with an extension from a small list of known extensions?  Can you access a list of all filenames before attempting the parsing?  Can you clean up your filesystem to remove spaces from the paths that house your source code?

Comment: @John1024, I just answered your questions in my updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the update with .cpp as the extension:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '/path/including whitespace/to/file.cpp function_name 1234 <any_content>'
>>> r = re.match(r'(?P<File>.+?\.cpp) (?P<Function>\w+) (?P<Linenum>[0-9]+) (?P<Content>.*)$', line)
>>> r.groupdict()
{'Function': 'function_name', 'Linenum': '1234', 'Content': '<any_content>', 'File': '/path/including whitespace/to/file.cpp'}
>>> r.groups()
('/path/including whitespace/to/file.cpp', 'function_name', '1234', '<any_content>')
```

The above assumes that ".cpp " will only appear in the filename only once at the end.  If that is acceptable, then the above should be fairly robust.

If you have multiple extensions, e.g. .cpp, .h, and .c, then:

```
>>> r = re.match(r'(?P<File>.+?\.(?:cpp|h|c)) (?P<Function>\w+) (?P<Linenum>[0-9]+) (?P<Content>.*)$', line)
```

The assumption is the same: an extension followed by a space appears only once in the file name at the end.  The file name match is non-greedy (`(?P<File>.+?\.(?:cpp|h|c))`) so that something that looks like an extension can appear in the content part without interfering with the match.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I think you also gave me a great tip in your comments above: I have the whole set of file paths already as a priori, so those can serve as a filter for the paths although with some performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will works on the sample:

```
st='/path/including whitespace/to/file.ext function_name 1234 <any_content>'

pat=re.compile(r'^(?P<Path>.+\.\S{,3})\s+(?P<Function>\w+)\s+(?P<Linenum>\d+)\s+(?P<Contents>.+)$')

m=pat.match(st)
print(m.groupdict())
print(list(m.group(1,2,3,4)))
```

Prints:

```
{'Contents': '<any_content>', 'Function': 'function_name', 'Path': '/path/including whitespace/to/file.ext', 'Linenum': '1234'}
['/path/including whitespace/to/file.ext', 'function_name', '1234', '<any_content>']
```

My SCO memory is fuzzy, but is `<any_content>` possibly multiline? If so, you can use [re.S](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) to match across lines:

```
st='''\
/path/including whitespace/to/file.h function_name 1234 <any_content .cpp>|
/path/including whitespace/to/file.cpp function_name 1234 <any_content 
   multiline>'''

pat=re.compile(r'^(?P<Path>.+\.\S{,3})\s+(?P<Function>\w+)\s+(?P<Linenum>\d+)\s+(?P<Contents>.+)', re.S)

for line in re.split(r'\|\n', st):
    m=pat.match(line)
    print(line)
    print(list(m.group(*['Path', 'Function', 'Linenum', 'Contents'])), '\n')
```

Prints:

```
/path/including whitespace/to/file.h function_name 1234 <any_content .cpp>
['/path/including whitespace/to/file.h', 'function_name', '1234', '<any_content .cpp>'] 

/path/including whitespace/to/file.cpp function_name 1234 <any_content 
   multiline>
['/path/including whitespace/to/file.cpp', 'function_name', '1234', '<any_content \n   multiline>']
```

You might want to [configure](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html) cscope to not print the path where trouble is likely to be found.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems to work. I will dig a bit deeper about cscope's config later.

Comment: Thanks so much for the re tips! <any_content> is always one line, but your tips about multiline situation are much appreciated. It'll be useful in the future.